# PowerShell script to list shared folders and sizes

Tags: powershell, shared-directory

Can anyone help me to create a powershell scripts to look at each server listed in the servers.txt, and report back the usage in MB on each shared folder, and the size and % of freespace on Q: (or all physical drives on the server)? Data for each server is to be saved as CSV. So for server1, a data file named server1.csv is to be created.

I did a search and I could find some scripts doing things similar but none completely fits in for my purpose, so I am seeing if someone would be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
function get_MB
{
get-content C:\temp\servers.txt

foreach($server in $servers)
{
$_.item | Measure-Object -property length -sum \1mb

out-file C:\temp\serverresults.txt
}
}
```